# Flutter redirect to new page on subscription event

Tags: flutter, supabase

I am using flutter with the supabase package. It sends a `Stream` of authentication events that I can listen to.

I just can't figure out how to redirect to a completely new page on such an auth event. For example, when the app receives a `passwordRecovery` event, then I want to drop the whole navigator stack and just show the `Reset Password` page. When the app receives a `signedIn` event, I want to drop the navigator stack and just show the HomePage.

This is what I am currently trying:

```
class AuthApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthApp> createState() => _AuthAppState();
}

class _AuthAppState extends State<AuthApp> {
  late final StreamSubscription<AuthState> _authStateSubscription;
  bool _isLoggedIn = supabaseClient.auth.currentSession != null;
  bool _resettingPassword = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _setupAuthStateSubscription();
  }

  void _setupAuthStateSubscription() {
    print('Setting up auth state subscription');
    _authStateSubscription =
        supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {
      final AuthChangeEvent event = data.event;
      final Session? session = data.session;

      print("Auth event: ${event.toString()}");

      setState(() {
        _currentUser = session?.user;
        _isLoggedIn = session != null;

        if (event == AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery) {
          _resettingPassword = true;
        }
      });
      if (event == AuthChangeEvent.signedOut ||
         event == AuthChangeEvent.signedIn ||
         event == AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery) {
       print('clearing navigator stack');
       Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widget),
         (route) => false,
       );
    });
  }
    
   Widget getNextPage() {
     if (_resettingPassword) {
        return const ResetPasswordScreen();
      } else if (_isLoggedIn) {
        return const MainApp();
       } else {
        return const WelcomeScreen();
     }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authStateSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getNextPage();
  }
}
```

Login does work, but for some reason on the password recovery event, the widget is disposed and I see the Home Page.

Comment: From what I can see, in every single case, the user is taken to a `widget` when signIn or passwordRecovery occurs, but in your actual app do you have it so that they are taken to a different page depending on the event?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Since the `AuthApp`widget rerenders, shouldn't a different page be shown when I call `setState`?

Answer (score 1):

`widget` variable will always contain the initial state of the widget. You can verify this with the following code.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _test = 'before presee';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _test = 'after press';
              });
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widget),
                  (route) => false);
            },
            child: Text(_test)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What might be better is to just have different widgets for login page or password recovery page and navigate to those pages depending what the event is.

```dart
if(event == AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>PasswordRecoveryPage()),
                  (route) => false);
} else {
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>LoginPage()),
                  (route) => false);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely good to know! I had ended up going with something similar. On any of these events, the Navigator just pops everything until the first route. Then `setState` is called and a new widget is shown because of the `build` method.